# having a trouble with java arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

what i need to do is to create an array that stores all the scores and display the numbers reversely. Help~~!!
This is so far I came up with.

//wbin

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public Class ArrayPractice
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int count = 0;
     int total = 0;
     final int SENTINEL = 0;
     int score;
     int sum;


     Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

     System.out.println( "Enter your score then Press 0 to display your average and total score. " );
     System.out.println( "When you are finished, Press 0" );

     System.out.print( "Enter the first test score > " );
     score = scan.nextInt( );

     while ( score != SENTINEL )
     {
        total = score + total;

        count++;

        System.out.print( "Enter the next test score > " );
        score = scan.nextInt( );
     }



     if ( count != 0 )
     {
        DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat( "##.0" );
        System.out.println("\nYour Average is "
          + oneDecimalPlace.format( (double) ( total  / count) ) );
          System.out.println("Your Total score is " + total);
}
         else
        System.out.println( "\nNo grades were entered" );

  }
}
```

Comment: `1)` ArrayList is not the same thing as array and you seem to be interchanging the 2 when you talk about them. `2)` I don't see an array OR an ArrayList in the code you provided.

Comment: You need to also add what you your problem was and what you are expecting.

Comment: rightnow i'm trying to figure out how to save the grades into the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Add the individual scores in your loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while ( score != SENTINEL )
 {
    scores.add(score)
    total = score + total;

    count++;

    System.out.print( "Enter the next test score > " );
    score = scan.nextInt( );
 }
```

you can do another loop for displaying your grades in reverse:

```
for(int i = scores.size(); i > 0; i--){
    System.out.println(scores.get(i));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for printing items in reverse order below

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int totalScore =0;
    while(true) {
        System.out.print( "Enter the test score > " );
        int score=scan.nextInt( );
        if(score==0) break;
        totalScore+=score;
        scores.add(score);
    }

    Collections.reverse(scores);

    for(int score:scores){
        System.out.println(score);
    }
```